# What is this round neon-green fruit with a bumpy surface?

Tags: identification, fruits

I have a vague recollection that this is called some kind of "apple" as a nickname.  But I just couldn't retrieve the exact name from memory.

[image]

Comment: Where is this? It looks like what we call a crab apple in TX.

Comment: @Philip, it's not crab apple.  Also I am quite taken aback by your claim that Texans call this crab apples.  Crab apples for me refers to "wild apples" as versus to cultivated apple cultivars.

Comment: @qazwsx Hmm looks like you're right. Either my memory is faulty or whoever told me that when I was a child had no idea what they're talking about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Osage orange *[Maclura pomifera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclura_pomifera)*, a.k.a hedge-apple. a.k.a. Bois d'arc and further mangled to bodark. The latter set of names have to do with the wood's suitability for archery bows.

Comment: Also you don't eat these

Comment: Growing up we called the fruit 'monkey balls' and kept them in our homes to discourage insects and spiders.  Wikipedia says they aren't effective but I still believe.

Answer (score 1):

In Brazil there's a fruit called "Jaca", Artocarpus heterophyllus.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackfruit

Comment: Oh, it's not it.  I've seen and ate jackfruit.